# How do I setup an alias for sub.sub.domain.com?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a QC server where we define the 'ServerName' for each QC site as a sub-domain in their VirtualHost file, using Named Virtual Hosts on Spache.  For example:

Site #1:

```
ServerName someproject.qcserver.com
```

Site #2:

```
ServerName someotehrproject.qcserver.com
```

I'm trying to setup an url like this:  es.someproject.qcserver.com

I tried:

```
ServerName someproject.qcserver.com 
ServerAlias es.someproject.qcserver.com
```

And restarted Apache, but es.someproject.qcserver.com isn't working.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly does `isn't working` mean. What is the error message you get and from what application? Are there any relevant error messages in your logs?

Comment: es.someproject.qcserver.com results in a server not found page.  No errors on httpd restart or in the error log.

Comment: Did you create a suitable DNS entry for `es.someproject.qcserver.com` ?

Comment: And may I testily note that, if that turns out to be the answer, we could have got you there in *seconds* if you hadn't redacted your domain names?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to create a suitable DNS entry for es.someproject.example.com which causes the client to fail to find it.

Suitable entries may be an A record pointing to the same IP address as someproject.example.com or a CNAME pointing to someproject.example.com.